# conan 2.0 cmake interface library

Tags: c++, cmake, interface, conan-2

I have a CMake project that creates an interface library with (only showing the critical section of CMakeLists.txt):

```
...
add_subdirectory(part1)
add_subdirectory(part2)
add_subdirectory(part3)
add_library(part_interface INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(part_interface INTERFACE 
                part1 
                part2 
                part3
)
...
```

Each of the subdirecties [lib1, lib2, lib3] contains a CMakeLists.txt that allows to build the different librairies.

I do not see how I could organize a generic conanfile.py to create a package for such an interface library? I would like it to pack all the sub-libraries as well as a global one (libinterface)?

I saw in the [documentation](https://github.com/conan-io/examples2/tree/main/examples/conanfile/layout/editable_components/greetings) the notion of components but I do not see how I could have something that would bind all the sub-libraries without having itself some sources? Should I have a conanfile.py for each sub-library?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just my two cents on how the design should work

> I do not see how I could organize a generic conanfile.py to create a package for such an interface library? I would like it to pack all the sub-libraries as well as a global one (libinterface)?

Strictly speaking components aren't exactly a *packing* thing, [ALL libraries are available by package, The package is always complete and include all components binaries](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/13851#issuecomment-1539620696).

> how I could have something that would bind all the sub-libraries without having itself some sources

you will have to write your own conanfile.py to explain to the pkg system how your build system works, as mentioned in that ticket, components are an "advance" use-case after-all.

> Should I have a conanfile.py for each sub-library

No. You should only have 1 class implementing ConanFile per package